# GWT - XML Parser - how to add new tag?

Tags: xml, gwt

I am following the gwt xml instructions from [here](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsXML.html#building) to build xml with gwt. The thing is I have already a xml in com.google.gwt.xml.client.Document object and I want to modify it. Here the xml structure which is parsed to the **Document**...

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<A>
<B>
<C>C1</C>
<C>C2</C>
<C>C3</C>
</B>
<B></B>
</A>
```

Next I want to add new `<B></B>` tags pair. I have noticed that there is no way to use code like a ...

```
Node node=new Node()
```

Here is the code I find "not working"

```
Element a=this.getDocument().getElementsByTagName("A").item(0);

        Element b=this.getDocument().createElement("B");
            b.setAttribute("attribute1", "B1");
            b.setAttribute("attribute2", "B2");
            a.appendChild(b);
```

For some reason it doesn't modify xml :( What am I doing wrong?

So my question is how can I add new tags pair to my Document not to recreate it?

All useful comments are appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  the [`Document`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/xml/client/Document.html)`#createFoo` methods:

```
Element b = document.createElement("B");
```

Comment: I am using it but there maybe something wrong with xml or something because it doesn't work correct :( Please watch my question again I edited it

Comment: How are you checking whether the DOM has been modified?

Comment: I get getDocument().toString() to see its content. Is it the right way?

Comment: It's not clear which document the `getDocument()` call refers to.